# WordPress performance issue. Can I debug it?

Tags: performance

I have a web site, that while working properly, every day, at 11:00am using a huge amounts of the server resources.

The web hosting account contains only the WordPress, and I don't have any other software installed.

Also, the hosting account is based on Cloud Linux, that means I can have statistics about my account resource usage.

Bellow you can see what is the resource usage of my account:

```
Your site has been limited within the past 24 hours
CPU resources were limited for your site
You have reached processes number limit 8 times
Your site might hit resource limits soon
Your Physical Memory usage was at 999.7M out of 1000.0M
You had 4000 I/O usage out of 4000 max I/O usage allowed
```

What I like to ask, is for any script, wordpress plugin or anything else that can help me identify, why I have that issue every day at the same time.

Note, already, I have use a plugin to get the WordPress schedule, and the schedule is ok. There is no, any action that run at 11:00 am. Also the server has no any cron job that run at the same time.

Comment: if the scheduling in wordpress is okay and you have no cron running at the given time, it should not be a wordpress problem. do you have a hosting provider or do you host the server yourself?

Comment: Have you checked for the following things - 1. Plug-ins/Scripts running on a schedule (this could be linked to WordPress or with your hosting account). 2. Checking the logs, at one time when I was facing similar problems with my WP based site, it turned out that someone from Chinese IPs was running a bot on my site trying to fill all forms with their mark-up. 3. Slow queries on WordPress. You can log this using the slow query log of mysql - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: I have check plugins with P3, I have check MySQL too. Also I have check the schedule too and there is no any schedule that run at 11:00 am either in WordPress or in Server via Cron jobs

Comment: Have you checked your traffic stats for this time of day? A misbehaved bot can wreak havoc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check the actual access logs, such as web, SSH, etc., and if you can access it, the MySQL log, too. That will show you what is possibly hitting the site at that time and let you differentiate between a huge unexplained web traffic spike from a bot and something that is happening in Wordpress or the theme itself, or on the server.

If it's a *shared* cloud server, you may be seeing spillover from another account, depending on how the accounts are configured.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to determining whether or not you're using too much resources generally you will need to look first to see if you're experiencing any faults which is displayed in the bottom graph in the cPanel -> Resource Usage section.  If you are seeing faults there's a good chance you either need to optimize your site or possibly upgrade to a plan that provides more CPU.  Optimizing such as installing and properly configuring a quality caching plugin is generally the best way to resolve the issue.